# How do i run electrical cord or extension across my sidewalk

Tags: electrical

Would like to add christmas lights to two trees that are across my sidewalk into the front most part of my lawn. I dont want to use tape!

Can anyone provide images or simple steps to do this?

Comment: `I dont want to use tape` .... what do you mean?

Comment: How commited are you? Willing to dig a few holes?

Comment: @jsotola it means he doesn't want to tape the cord down.

Answer (score 6):

Obtain some Rigid conduit, which threads like pipe.  Note, it threads like pipe, so you can attach water hose adapters.

Dig holes in the right places and hydraulically drive the Rigid conduit under the sidewalk.  You can trench and continue the Rigid conduit up toward the house if you want to, depth must be at least 6". Stop somewhere short of the house.  This won't be going inside.

At both ends of the conduit, terminate them in a type of junction box designed to sit flush on a lawn and be run over by mowers without incident.  Pull or push through white, black and green #12 THWN wire.

In the box nearer the house, fit an **inlet**. This is a reverse socket that takes the non-prongy end of an extension cord.

In the other box, fit a normal outlet. A GFCI+receptacle combo device here is not required  nor recommended.

This thing is just a jumper.  It's not officially part of your house wiring and is not energized unless you plug an extension cord into the inlet.  As such it won't need the full monty permitting and inspection, and you won't need to alter your house wiring at all or work near anything hot.

Now on the far side of your sidewalk, you have really great power.  With great power comes great responsibility. Feed this rig from a GFCI protected circuit.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of three options...

For a temporary solution, you could use a cord protector (those little plastic/rubber ramp things you see at carnivals and other outdoor events). Just put it on the sidewalk, and route you cables through it.

For a semi-permanent solution, you could install a conduit sleeve under the sidewalk.  Just make sure it's large enough to fit the cord ends through.

If you're looking for something more permanent.  You could install a permanent electrical circuit out to where you need it.  This will require trenching, conduit or underground feeder cable, weatherproof boxes, and GFCI protection.

Comment: How much would option three run and can you explain more on option two?  Im afraid option one could be dangerous as we get a good amount of foot traffic and someone could fall

Comment: Tester has all the options listed, a new circuit would depend on the permit cost and the distance, a gfci can be purchased for under 15$ wether proof boxes and in use cover or extra heavy duty cover needed for out side work can tip the scales at 50$ for quality diecast. The UF wire will depend on the length I use #12 in most cases, and last a 20 amp breaker are most of the supplies needed (a few feet of schedule 80 conduit to protect the wire from the box to 18" below ground).